# How to escape html code to insert in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am using tinymce editor to have html page and then insert it in mysql.
I tried this:

```
 $esdata = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
```

it is working for all html *except* images. If I have hyperlink like:

```
http://www.abc.com/pic.jpg
```

then it makes it somewhat very obscure and the image doesn't appear.

INPUT
`<img src="../images/size-chart.jpg" alt="Beer" />`

OUPUT
`<img src="\&quot;&quot;images/size-chart.jpg\\&quot;\&quot;" alt="\&quot;Beer" />`

Comment: Are you un-escaping at output?

Comment: If you don't want guessed answers, show an example of what the mangled image links(?) look like. Also show code of how exactly you are inserting it into the database and how you output it.

Comment: Be aware that tinyMCE has some functionality to "support" you... this could be the reason for the strange output, too! Just double check by outputting your content via echo outside of tinyMCE and the normal way inside tinyMCE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `urlencode` and `urldecode` to escape the string.
As Christian said it is not used for the sake of DB but to keep the things as it is. So you can also use `urlencode` and `urldecode`.

For Ex:

```
//to encode
$output = urlencode($input);


//to decode
$input = urldecode($output);
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't over-escape code before you send it to DB.

When you escape it, it's done in a way that it is stored in the DB as it was originally. Escaping is not done for the sake of the DB, but for the sake of keeping the data as it was without allowing users to inject bad stuff in your sql statements (prior to sending the stuff in the DB).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function to encode the string and [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) to display the string back to html